# Javascript sort with condition gives out of order result

Tags: javascript, sorting

Before I start I've looked at a lot of posts but i don't know how to solve this issue. I have a an array which I'm sorting with a condition as following, I want any array item which matches the tablePrefix on top. When the number of items in array is 10 OR less than 10 its works like a charm but when it is 11 OR more the function starts giving wrong sorting order.

```
var tablePrefix = 'es_officer';

columns = [
           "es_officer_id", // 0
           "es_officer_name", // 1
           "es_officer_fname", // 2
           "es_officer_dob", // 3
           "es_officer_apply_status", // 4
           "es_employment_type_id", // 5
           "es_employment_type_name", // 6
           "es_designation_id", // 7
           "es_designation_title", // 8
           "es_service_type_id", // 9
           "es_service_type_name", // 10 
           "es_bps_id", // 11
           "es_bps_title" // 12
          ];

columns.sort((a, b) => a.indexOf(tablePrefix) ? a.localeCompare(b) : -1);

console.log(columns);
```

**Result with 12 items in array**

```
[
  "es_officer_id",
  "es_officer_fname",
  "es_officer_dob",
  "es_officer_apply_status",
  "es_bps_id",
  "es_officer_name", // Unordered result, this should be above es_bps_id
  "es_bps_title",
  "es_designation_id",
  "es_designation_title",
  "es_employment_type_id",
  "es_employment_type_name",
  "es_service_type_id",
  "es_service_type_name"
]
```

but if remove any two items and reduce the no of items in columns array to 10 it works fine. for example lets remove 9 and 10.

**Result with 10 items in array**

```
[
  "es_officer_id",
  "es_officer_fname",
  "es_officer_dob",
  "es_officer_apply_status",
  "es_officer_name", // In right order 
  "es_bps_id",
  "es_bps_title",
  "es_designation_id",
  "es_designation_title",
  "es_employment_type_id",
  "es_employment_type_name"
]
```

Anyone ?? help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your sort is only sorting anything that does NOT start with the table prefix.  For items that start with the prefix, `index_of` is returning 0, which is falsy, so all items that start with the prefix always return -1, not an actual comparison

Comment: OK, if its not sorting why is "es_officer_name" is under "es_bps_id" ?? I'm keeping all es_officer on top so that they don't get sorted but why the last one is getting sorted and how do you propose to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting algorithms assume a total consistent ordering. This means that it must not be possible that both `a < b` and `b < a`, but this is what happens when you compare two elements matching the prefix as your comparison function will return `-1` even if you swap the elements.

If you violate algorithm requirements about comparison function then anything can happen (for example a bubble sort algorithm would loop forever). Apparently the ECMA standard is more forgiving and just talks about arbitrary implementation-defined sort order: hang, crash or element duplication/deletion is not going to happen in a standard implementation.

Note also that if `a` matches you need to check if `b` matches too before using `localCompare` if you want all matching to appear before.

```
function comp(a, b) {
   if (a.indexOf(prefix)) {
      if (b.indexOf(prefix)) {
          return a.localCompare(b);
      } else {
          return 1;
      }
   } else {
      if (b.indexOf(prefix)) {
          return -1;
      } else {
          return 0; // All prefixed are considered equal
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this logic worked... but there are two syntax errors in the code just for the reference for others. 1: The first sub if is not closed which gives syntax error 2: its localeCompare NOT localcompare... but thanks anyways, i appreciate it.

Comment: hey I've another question related to sorting, actually its related to this question as well, should i open a new post or edit this one ??

Comment: @Wcan: unless is extremely related first check if the question is already answered on SO and if it's not then ask a new one...

Answer (score 1):

Sorts both items that start with `tablePrefix` and items that don't.  Items that start with the prefix come first

```js
var tablePrefix = 'es_officer';

var columns = [
           "es_officer_id", // 0
           "es_officer_name", // 1
           "es_officer_fname", // 2
           "es_officer_dob", // 3
           "es_officer_apply_status", // 4
           "es_employment_type_id", // 5
           "es_employment_type_name", // 6
           "es_designation_id", // 7
           "es_designation_title", // 8
           "es_service_type_id", // 9
           "es_service_type_name", // 10
           "es_bps_id", // 11
           "es_bps_title" // 12
          ];


columns.sort((a, b) =>
{
    if (a.startsWith(tablePrefix) == b.startsWith(tablePrefix)) {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    }
    if (a.startsWith(tablePrefix)) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (b.startsWith(tablePrefix)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0; 
});

console.log(columns);
```

Comment: Thanks really help full.

Answer (score -2):

All you need to do is to return true for all the string that has a given prefix so they are considered as a lower and pushes them first.

```js
var tablePrefix = 'es_service';

columns = [
  "es_officer_id", // 0
  "es_officer_name", // 1
  "es_officer_fname", // 2
  "es_officer_dob", // 3
  "es_officer_apply_status", // 4
  "es_employment_type_id", // 5
  "es_employment_type_name", // 6
  "es_designation_id", // 7
  "es_designation_title", // 8
  "es_service_type_id", // 9
  "es_service_type_name", // 10 
  "es_bps_id", // 11
  "es_bps_title" // 12
];

columns.sort((a, b) => a.indexOf(tablePrefix) ? 1 : -1);

console.log(columns);
```

Comment: I've already tried this one the problem is the es_officer part is fine but it does not sort rest of the array